# How to define CF resource as function event source in serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-iot

I'm trying to create a AWS Lambda with the serverless framework. The Lambda is triggered through an AWS IoT Topic Rule. In case the execution of the Rule fails I want to have an error action executed. The entire configuration should take place within the *serverless.yml*.

As far as I can tell from the [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/iot/) there is no option to describe an `errorAction` for an iot event:

```yaml
functions:
  foobar:
    events:
      - iot:
          errorAction: ?
```

It is possible though to define a Cloud Formation resource with an `ErrorAction` inside the *serverless.yml*:

```yaml
resources:
  Resources:
     FoobarIotTopicRule1:
       Type: AWS::IoT::TopicRule
       Properties:
           ErrorAction:
             Republish:
               RoleArn: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/service-role/iot_execution_role
               Topic: FAILURE
```

But then I don't know how to link the resource to act as a trigger of the Lambda function.

```yaml
functions:
  foobar:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - iot:
          name: iot_magic_rule
          sql: "SELECT * FROM 'my/dedicated/topic'"
          enabled: true
          sqlVersion: '2016-03-23'

resources:
  Resources:
     FoobarIotTopicRule1:
       Type: AWS::IoT::TopicRule
       Properties:
         RuleName: iot_magic_rule
         TopicRulePayload:
           AwsIotSqlVersion: '2016-03-23'
           RuleDisabled: false
           Sql: "SELECT * FROM 'my/dedicated/topic'"
           ErrorAction:
             Republish:
               RoleArn: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/service-role/iot_execution_role
               Topic: FAILURE
```

With the above configuration, trying to deploy on AWS fails as Cloud Formation tries to create the AWS IoT Topic Rule twice. Once for the definition in `events` and once as the defined resource `FoobarIoTTopicRule1`.

**EDIT1**

Defining the Lambda action inside the IoTTopicRule resource, creates the rule as intended, with Lambda action and error event. Unfortunately the rule does not show up as a trigger within the Lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to define an AWS IoT Topic Rule with an `ErrorAction` that will also show up as a trigger event on AWS Lambda, the configuration should look somewhat like this:

```
functions:
  foobar:
    handler: index.handler

resources:
  Resources:
     FoobarIotTopicRule1:
       Type: AWS::IoT::TopicRule
       Properties:
         RuleName: iot_magic_rule
         TopicRulePayload:
           AwsIotSqlVersion: '2016-03-23'
           RuleDisabled: false
           Sql: "SELECT * FROM 'my/dedicated/topic'"
           Actions:
             - Lambda:
                 FunctionArn: { "Fn::GetAtt": ['FoobarLambdaFunction', 'Arn']}
           ErrorAction:
             Republish:
               RoleArn: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/service-role/iot_execution_role
               Topic: FAILURE
     FoobarLambdaPermissionIotTopicRule1:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties: 
        FunctionName: { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "FoobarLambdaFunction", "Arn" ] }
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: { "Fn::Join": ["", [ "iot.", { "Ref": "AWS::URLSuffix" } ]]}
        SourceArn: 
          Fn::Join: 
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
              - ":iot:"
              - "Ref": "AWS::Region"
              - ":"
              - "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
              - ":rule/"
              - "Ref": "FoobarIotTopicRule1"
```